# Multi level categorical excel data representation with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following data structure in excel:

[image]

I was wondering if it is possible to plot the reported structure in a clear way for others to gain insights. I thought about using a multilabeled bar plot with seaborn library but i think its a messy representation. Do you suggest any clear representation? i thank you for your help and time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was a really handful library called Treemap in python. The library allows a really clear visualization of the previously mentioned structure.